# Reading char[] from web-service by HttpGet — strange behavior

Tags: java, android, network-programming, streaming

I am developing an Android application, it is going to fetch a big chunk of JSON data in stream. Calling the web service is OK, but I have a little problem. In my old version I was using Gson for reading the stream then I've tried to insert data to database, it was OK without any problem except performance. So I tried to change approach of loading data, I am trying to read data to `char[]` first then insert them to database.

This is my new code:

```
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
final int contentLength = (int) responseEntity.getContentLength();
InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);

int readCount = 10 * 1024;
int hasread = 0;
char[] buffer = new char[contentLength];
int mustWrite = 0;
int hasread2 = 0;
while (hasread < contentLength) {
    // problem is here
    hasread += reader.read(buffer, hasread, contentLength - hasread);
}

Reader reader2 = new CharArrayReader(buffer);
```

The problem is that the reader starts reading correctly but at near of the end of stream, the `hasread` variable value decreases (by `1`) instead of increasing. Very strange to me, and then the `while` loop never finishes. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Saw your post.Can you please add some light on how you resolved this .

Answer (score 2):

You should use a fixed size for the buffer, not the size of whole data (the `contentLength`). And an *important* note: the length of a `char[]` array is different to `byte[]` array's. The `char` data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. While the `byte` data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.

Also your `while` loop is wrong, you can fix it as:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

private static final int BUF_SIZE = 10 * 1024;

// ...

HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
final int contentLength = (int) responseEntity.getContentLength();
InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(stream);

int hasread = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
while ((hasread = reader.read(buffer, 0, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
    // For example, convert the buffer to a String
    String data = new String(buffer, 0, hasread, "UTF-8");
}
```

Make sure to use your own charset (`"UTF-8"`, `"UTF-16"`…).

Comment: It's get reading ok by Gson (streaming model), but I wont use Gson.

Comment: Error at execution <recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)>

Comment: @Lia Vung what if I use InputStreamReader ?, What's major difference between InputStreamReader and BufferedStreamReader ?. what's wrong in the first code (my code) ?. because it is not getting any error just wrong value in the end of stream which is getting by hasread veriable .

Comment: @Areff Because [`InputStreamReader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) doesn't support reading data into a `byte[]` array, it just supports `char[]` array. But the length you receive from server is always the length of total *bytes* of data. And I think one of the errors you're facing is *the wrong value in the end of stream* …